# How to sum values in Excel that occur between 2 hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I would like to sum the sales depending on the time diapasons of the day-night in which they occur. For example, I would like to sum all sales that happened between 22:00h and 2:00h.

```
Hour    Sales
18:58   49
18:00   49.5
03:01   31
20:00   139
09:15   61.5
11:36   5
08:00   24
16:32   25
12:30   96.5
17:30   75.5
09:00   80
00:10   24
15:00   24
18:00   216
09:30   24
06:30   47.5
```

So if I try to do a sumifs where the hour is >=22:00 and <23:00, the formula works. However, if I try to sumifs the values between 22:00 and 2:00, in other words the first criteria is ">=22:00" and the second is "<2:00", the sumifs cannot work. I do understand why but I'm struggling to find an alternative way to solve this task.

Comment: You could do two sumifs. One from 22:00 to 0:00 and another from 0:00 to 2:00 am

Comment: Times are just a portion of a day and a day is nothing more than an integer 1 =). Therefor, 2:00 is smaller than 22:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, we need to add 1 when it rolls to the next day, which means SUMPRODUCT:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$17,((E2<D2)+$A$2:$A$17>=D2)*(($A$2:$A$17<D2)+$A$2:$A$17<(E2<D2)+E2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is why I like data that holds Date+Time values. Sidenote: I wonder how OP distinguishes between sales made between morning and next morning (if that makes sense) +

Comment: @JvdV yup, if there is a date value attached to the data but not shown, this will not work.

Comment: There is a date value but for the purpose of my analysis, I need to find out what % of bookings happened in what part of the day night. I totally don't understand this formula but it works and I will use it. thanks!